# Deleted page URLs

Tags: entries, url

We're having a bit of a problem with the unique URL system in Craft. An entry was deleted, and a new one has been created to replace it. However the new entry should have the same URL as the old removed one, but Craft is insisting on appending -2, -3, etc to the entry URL.

Is this a bug? There is currently no way to recover a deleted page in the CMS, and I can't find a way to purge previously deleted entry URLs without editing the database directly.

Has anyone got any idea? Is this a bug, or is there a solution? Obviously when handed over to a client I can't ask them to just pop into MySQL and remove old entries.

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Hey Ian - Just tried this on my local machine and was able to create a new entry with an old URL without any issue. Are you using a channel, structure, or single for this section?

Comment: Hi Aaron, I've not noticed this problem before either. Not sure why it's behaving like this now. I'm guessing it's a bug of some kind. It's a structure item.

Comment: Can you submit a ticket through the control panel so I can take a closer look at your logs and database?

Comment: I've submitted a ticket. This seems to be occurring on three of our current builds all running 2.4.2691. They were all created from the same Craft build we use as a starting point. I'm not getting that error on a client site built from scratch (now running 2.4.2684).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, database tables on this Craft project were missing foreign key constraints, and since Craft relies on the CASCADING DELETE/UPDATE functionality of these foreign keys, it was not deleting all associated rows across tables for a deleted entry. This can happen when migrating a database backup to a server that only supports MyISAM and not InnoDB because MyISAM will silently drop the foreign key constraints.

If this happens, you can use the [Craft Foreign Key Restoration Tool](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/craft-fixfks) to try and restore the missing foreign keys.